# Coincidencia parcial en Regex Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Necesito encontrar la ultima coincidencia entre un string y una Regex, o dicho de otra manera darme cuenta si es posible que el string este "en camino" de cumplir con la Regex. Basicamente simular el comportamiento de hitEnd() de Java en Javascript.

Un ejemplo es:

```js
const pattern = /cvd(d|w)*x/;
const sequence1 = 'cv';
const sequence2 = 'cvw';
```

El cual necesitaria que en sequence1 me devuelva true porque va por "buen camino", y en sequence2 me devuelva false porque ya no es posible cumplir con la regex.
Existe algo asi en JS? Estuve buscando en npm si algo sirve, pero no encontre.
Gracias